# override javascript function

Tags: javascript, joomla

`Joomla.submitbutton` is a core javascript function in joomla. this function called in submit form when user click on cancel button or save button .I overwrite this function like this.

```
savefn=Joomla.submitbutton ;
Joomla.submitbutton =function() {  
    timeval=jQuery("div.controls > input#jform_longth.inputbox").val();
    if(timeval.length < 8){
        alert("Enter time in correct format");
    }
    else {
        savefn('settime.save') ;
    }
}
```

when user click on save button `Joomla.submitbutton('settime.save')` called and when user click on cancel button `Joomla.submitbutton('settime.cancel')` called. how I can determine user click on cancel button or save button .
In other words, how i can get argument on `Joomla.submitbutton` when i overwrite function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use argument within your function like below:

```
if(arguments[0].toLowerCase()=='save'){

} else{

}
```

Comment: this not working.this error show in console "argument is not defined"

Comment: I think argument must change to arguments.

Answer (score 1):

An example from Joomla docs:

```
var submitbuttonfn = Joomla.submitbutton;
Joomla.submitbutton = function(pressbutton) {

    console.log(pressbutton);

    if (pressbutton == 'cancel') {
        submitbuttonfn(pressbutton);
    }
    else {
        var f = document.adminForm;
        if (document.formvalidator.isValid(f)) {
            submitbuttonfn(pressbutton);
        }
        else {
            alert('Validation error');
        }
    }
}
```